# Citation on heuristic definition of the Dirac delta function

Tags: reference-request, definition, dirac-delta

The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Definitions) on the Dirac delta function offers the following *heuristic* definition of the Dirac delta function:

$$\delta(x) = \begin{cases} +\infty, & x = 0 \\ 0, & x \ne 0 \end{cases}$$

whilst acknowledging that the Dirac delta function in fact needs to rigorously defined as either a distribution or a measure. My question is does anyone know of a citation/reference on this in either a textbook or academic journal article?

Comment: This definition of the Dirac $\delta$ function surely over half a century old.  (I don't know the first reference.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch a review on "Basic Circuit Theory"

[https://www.amazon.com/Basic-Circuit-Theory-Charles-Desoer/dp/0070165750](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0070165750)